# Counting nested categories in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, grouping

**Aim:**
Get a summary table of counts of categories that are nested within another category.

**Example:**
I have this dataframe:

```
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'jack', 'jack', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Jim', 'Jim'],
        'CEFR_level': ['A1', 'A2', 'PreA1', 'A2', 'A1','A1','B1','C1', 'A1', 'B1']}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# I use this code to recode:

Easy = ["PreA1","A1", "A2"]
Medium =["B1", "B2"]
Hard = ["C1", "C2"]

data ['CEFR_categories'] = np.where(data['CEFR_level'].isin(Easy), 'Easy',
                                               np.where(data['CEFR_level'].isin(Medium), 'Medium',
                                                        np.where(data ['CEFR_level'].isin(Hard), 'Hard', 'Other')))
```

I managed to make the column: data ['CEFR_categories'] and categorize properly the Easy, Medium and Hard.

My problem is with the groupby.

**Task:**
**DONE**
I want to recode the X, Y and Z into easy, medium and hard.

I then I want to groupby combining categories. For example, the new easy category, repeats 2 times (Tom (who has in the CEFR_level 'A1', 'A2', 'PreA1') and Jack (who has A1 and A2 in the CEFR level)). Easy-Medium-Hard (repeats 1 time for Mary (which a different combination of CEFR_level which is then recoded to easy, medium and hard)) and Easy-Medium repeats 1 time for Jim.

I have for hours tried to recode this, I can recode into another column but I only have 1 category (for example) easy for the first row. (With the code above)

My output should look like this:

[image]

How can i group by this.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT and UPDATE**

I used @Timeless answer I got the following output:

[image]

Any suggestions? The first 4 lines in my real data has a cat1 of: easy, easy, easy, medium. Which would result in a Easy-Medium.

But the ouput says there is none.

**Final answer**

This code by timeless also works.

```
cats = sorted(testlet_item_bank["CEFR_categories"].unique()) 
#status = dict(zip(cats, ["Easy", "Medium", "Hard"])) # this was mixing categories

ps = list(map("-".join, powerset(cats)))[1:]

out = (
      testlet_item_bank # the first chain can be optional
      .astype({"CEFR_categories": pd.CategoricalDtype(cats, ordered=True)})
      .groupby("TestletID")["CEFR_categories"]
      .agg(lambda x: "-".join(pd.unique(x.sort_values())))
      .value_counts()
      .reindex(ps, fill_value=0)
      .rename_axis("Categories")
      .reset_index(name="Counts")
#    .replace(status, regex=True) this mixes categories
)
```

Comment: Your requirements are extremely confusing as written; more specifically, I think your use of the word "repeats" is not as specific or clear as you might think. Can you try to clarify by sharing your expected output and your previous attempts as [mre]s, along with succinct explanations of why those previous attempts didn't meet your requirements?

Comment: Ok, I put more detailed so my question is easier to understand.

Comment: Why would Mary be `Medium-Hard` when she has `Cat1` values including all three of `X`, `Y`, and `Z`? In your expected output and based on your broader explanation of the requirements, I'd expect that would land in `Easy-medium-hard`, no?

Comment: True, my bad! I will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)/[`powerset`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.powerset) :

```
from more_itertools import powerset

mapper = {
    "Easy": ["PreA1", "A1", "A2"],
    "Medium": ["B1", "B2"],
    "Hard": ["C1", "C2"],
}

status = {v: k for k,lst_v in mapper.items() for v in lst_v}

df["CEFR_level"] = (
    df["CEFR_level"].map(status).fillna("Other")
    .astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(list(mapper) + ["Other"], ordered=True))
)

ps = list(map("-".join, powerset(mapper)))[1:]

out = (
    df # the first chain can be optional
    .groupby("Name")["CEFR_level"]
    .agg(lambda x: "-".join(pd.unique(x.sort_values())))
    .value_counts()
    .reindex(ps, fill_value=0)
    .rename_axis("Categories")
    .reset_index(name="Counts")
)
```

***NB** : If you can't install `more_itertools`, you can use [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from the docs.*

Output :

```
         Categories  Counts
0              Easy       2
1            Medium       0
2              Hard       0
3       Easy-Medium       1
4         Easy-Hard       0
5       Medium-Hard       0
6  Easy-Medium-Hard       1

[7 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that in my real data there are some problems. The first name (Tom) in my real data has cat1 easy, easy, easy and medium and the out table shows there are no Easy-medium (says Easy-medium = 0). Also, there are categories like "Easy-Hard-Hard" in the groupby table.

Comment: If you can provide the example when the code fails, I'll be happy to update it.

Comment: I see that you updated your post. That's normal if the code fails because you chanted the logic. Do you literally have values like `X`, `X1`, (*i.e* with eventually an increment as a suffix) ? Also, what about `Other` ? In any case, you still need to take a step back and clarify the logic because you don't seem to be sure about what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code and it is with real values. Hope this clarifies the problem. Sorry for the troubles and thanks for the guidance.

Comment: No worries ;) I updated the answer and hopefully it handles your second/real dataset.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I found the problem that also fixed the output. The #status = dict(zip(cats, ["Easy", "Medium", "Hard"])) was mixing up the categories. Thank you very much for the patience!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a relatively low complexity way, but be forewarned the performance of this may leave something to be desired at scale:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'jack', 'jack', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Jim', 'Jim'],
        'Cat1': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X','X','Y','Z', 'X', 'Y']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# First, sort by name then `Cat1` value to maintain the eventual ordering of `Easy`/`Medium`/`Hard`
df.sort_values(['Name', 'Cat1'], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

# De-dupe rows
df = df.drop_duplicates()

# Map X, Y, Z to Easy, Medium, Hard
df['Cat1'] = df['Cat1'].replace(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard'])

# Roll up levels grouped by unique Name value
df = df.groupby('Name').agg({'Cat1': '-'.join})

# Rename Cat1 column to 'counts' to match spec
df = df.rename(columns={"Cat1": "counts"})

# Get value_counts() of resulting `counts` column
return_value = df.value_counts('counts')
```

Result:

```
counts
Easy                2
Easy-Medium         1
Easy-Medium-Hard    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

The result here doesn't include 0 quantity category combinations, but it'd be trivial to work that aspect in if you absolutely require it.

Comment: Thanks! In this case it just for POC so there is no harm. But yeah, I get your point to do it on a bigger scale. Thanks and sorry the troubles reaching the solution.